# Show searched links url in command line with watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new in Ruby and now i'm trying to use watir. So i need to display all founded urls in my command line. Here is the beginning of my code:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new 

puts "1. Entering Google"
browser.goto "http://www.google.com"
search_text = "text"
puts " 2. enter "+ search_text +" in the search text field."
browser.text_field(:name, "q").set search_text
puts "3. click the 'Google Search' button."
browser.button(:name, "btnG").click
puts " First 10 links: "
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The links are stored inside h3 tag with class name of 'r', so you can get the collection of link elements by:

```
links = browser.h3s(class: 'r').map(&:link)
```

The url is stored in the href tag, so you can get an array of href values by:

```
hrefs = links.map(&:href)
```

So to print this:

```
hrefs.each { |href| puts href }
```

But some of those hrefs go through a redirect, so you might want to do this:

```
links.each { |link| puts "#{link.data_href || link.href}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic approach to pulling links from a specific page element.  It specifies the container element (i.e. a `div` tag), collects the [links](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#links-instance_method) in that container, and prints the `text` for each link (or each `href` -- depending on what's specified in the block):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto('http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved')

b.div(class: "navigation").links.each { |link| puts link.text}
b.div(class: "navigation").links.each { |link| puts link.href}
```