# Ruby Watir: Display hyperlinks from a chrome search

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir

Objective: To print out an array of hyperlinks searched from a couple of keywords input to a search engine, chrome in this case, utilizing Watir.

Thing is my code below used to work fine over the last year. Tested it many times but something has changed within the confines of Chrome and the elements or selectors or perhaps watir has deprecated some functionality but I'm using very few lines of ruby code. It just hangs.(*Edit* No results are produced in the terminal, doesn't actually hang) I've gone over this painstakingly and only one other link with a similar case, where I got my previous code from, but now it no longer works: [Show searched links url in command line with watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949773/show-searched-links-url-in-command-line-with-watir)

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new:chrome

browser.goto 'google.com'
browser.text_field(title: 'Search').set 'watir + ruby'
browser.button(name: 'btnK').click
sleep 3
links = browser.h3s(class: 'r').map(&:link)
hrefs = links.map(&:href)
links.each { |link| puts "#{link.data_href || link.href}" }

sleep(900)
```

Desired output (used to work)
[Terminal Displaying hyperlinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3bb8.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "it just hangs"? Is there an exception? If it's the browser not connecting, you will want to double-check that your Chromedriver, Watir and Selenium-WebDriver are up-to-date.

Comment: Note that the markup of the Google results appears to have changed. You'll need `links = browser.divs(class: 'r').map(&:link)` (changing `h3s` to `divs`). This would only cause no results as opposed to a hang, so I'm guessing isn't the immediate problem.

Comment: @JustinKo You are 100% correct. Google results changed my targeted html element to a css selector. It switched from 'h3s' to 'divs'. 

And thank you for the feedback on your initial comment. The browser would connect but wouldn't produce an output or error. (this is my first stack overflow question, thank you for your quick response!)

Answer (score 0):

Working script now produces search results hyperlinks (credit to Justin Ko) :

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new:chrome

browser.goto 'google.com'
browser.text_field(title: 'Search').set 'watir + ruby'
browser.button(name: 'btnK').click
sleep 3
puts browser.title
links = browser.divs(class: 'r').map(&:link)
hrefs = links.map(&:href)
# hrefs.each { |href| puts href }
links.each { |link| puts "#{link.data_href || link.href}" }

sleep(900)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXvtT.png)